# jQuery Horizontal Cursor Scrolling

Tags: jquery, scroll, cursor

I am trying to make a horizontal scroll system that uses the cursor.

The way it works is if the cursor's X position is at the very left of the screen,
The page should be at 0% horizontal scroll.

If the cursor's X position is at the very right of the screen,
The page should be at 100% horizontal scroll.

How can I achieve this?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the position of the mouse pointer relative to the left of document with `event.pageX` and set the scroll using `scrollLeft()`:

```
$(document).mousemove(function (e) {
    var winW = $(window).width(),
        docW = $(this).width(),
        i = docW / winW, //increment value
        x = (e.pageX - $(window).scrollLeft()) * i;

    $(window).scrollLeft(x);
});
```

See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m28EY/4

Comment: My explanation mustn't have been good enough. I want it so the scrollbar just touches the very right of the document as the cursor does. In your example, the scrollbar touches the right side before the cursor does. I hope this describes my problem better :)

Comment: ah yes a part of the document is already shown on window so you may need to subtract the windows width: `docW = $(this).width() - winW`. See this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m28EY/5/

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much. I had so much trouble with this and you just proved it to be so simple. Cheers!